# Sonar Unknown char error for files with UTF-8

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

When sonar scans my .net project, I get the following error messages. Where is the problem,thanks

Sonar version: 3.3.2

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

```
17:24:08.040 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:177:51)
17:24:08.040 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:177:53)
17:24:08.040 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:177:55)
17:24:08.040 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:177:57)
17:24:08.040 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:177:59)
17:24:08.040 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:177:61)
17:24:08.041 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:181:11)
17:24:08.041 WARN  nownCharacterChannel - Unknown char: "" (file:/......../HtmlModule.ascx.cs:181:13)
```

Source code;

```
��using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Collections; 
......
```

Comment: Check if `HtmlModule.ascx.cs` is UTF-8, too.

Answer (score 4):

If you're developing a .NET solution on Windows, chances are that your project is not encoding in UTF-8 but in cp-1252. Try with this encoding for "sonar.sourceEncoding".

Comment: In our case here we have mixed encoding for files in the same project. Is it possible to tell sonar that it will need to find out the encoding of the files? Is it possible to set multiple encodings?

Comment: Sorry Fabricio, but this is not possible in Sonar to have multiple encodings for a single project. And actually, this is a bad practice to do so (which in fact is why Sonar does not allow this)

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam  Of course it's bad practice to have multiple encodings in a project, that does not stop a 20+years old codebase from having that condition, and when you have 250+MB in your source-code subdirectory changing to a new (UTF-8) encoding in a "Big-Bang" is not a Good Idea. Do SonarQube still require a single encoding?

Answer (score 1):

By default .net and Java Properties plugin uses ISO-8859-1 to parse properties files. This behavior causes build failures, because our files are encoded in UTF-8.

solution: add parameter -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=utf-8 to sonar analysis